# How do I merge three UPDATE code in SQL into one?

Tags: sql-server

Please, I  am trying to update a promotion table with a single update query in SQL Server, but I don't know how to go about it. Though, I can only update the promotion table with multiple lines of code. I am trying to merge the three update query into one. I need one line of code to will perform this update.
I would be grateful if I can get this solution.

```
my_cursor.execute("UPDATE promos SET next_promotion = (last_promotion + 4) WHERE grade_level IN (14, 15, 16, 17, 18)")    
        
my_cursor.execute("UPDATE promos SET next_promotion = (last_promotion + 3) WHERE grade_level IN (7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13)")
       
my_cursor.execute("UPDATE promos SET next_promotion = (last_promotion + 2) WHERE grade_level IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `case` expression:

```
UPDATE promos
    SET next_promotion = last_promotion +
                          (CASE WHEN grade_level IN (14,15,16,17,18) THEN 4
                                WHEN grade_level IN (7,8,9,10,11,12,13) THEN 3
                                WHEN grade_level IN (1,2,3,4,5,6) THEN 2
                                ELSE next_promotion
                           END);
```

I'm not sure if you still need to filter for the `update`.